# Check if a set is an ideal in a ring and if it is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

We are given the map $f: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ and the ideals $I_5 = (5), I_6=(6), I_9=(9)$ as well as their images $I_5 = (5), I_6=(6), I_9=(9).$ I need to find which of the given ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ are prime.

I do not understand how the homomorphism works given the details about the ideals above. In particular, I do not see why $I_5, I_6, I_9$ are ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}.$ It seems that the elements of one such ideal are spread out among different cosets in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}.$

Also, I can check that $I_5 = (5)$ is prime and $I_6 = (6), I_9 = (9)$ are not prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}.$ But I do not see how to check for being prime for these ideals in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}.$

Can somebody provide some explanation or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: This is indeed a confusing notation. But I believe they just mean $(5)=(5+12\mathbb{Z})$. To check whether each ideal is prime or not, recall that the correspondence theorem preserves prime ideals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the notation $I_k$ both for ideals in $\mathbb Z$ and for ideals in $\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$. This is going to get confusing. So I'll use the notation  $I_k$ only for ideals in $\mathbb Z$, and I'll use $f(I_k)$ to denote the image of $I_k$ in $\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$ under the homomorphism $f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$.

The homomorphism $f$ is defined as
$$ f(n) = [n]_{\text{mod } 12}.$$

The ideal $I_k \subset \mathbb Z$ is defined as
$$ I_k = (k) = \{ kn : n \in \mathbb Z \} $$

So its image under the homormorphism $f$ is
$$ f(I_k) = \{  [kn]_{\text{mod } 12} : n \in \mathbb Z \} $$

Having written it out this way, hopefully you can see that $f(I_k)$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$ - it is an abelian group and it is closed under multiplication by arbitrary elements of  $\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$ .

---

Let's work through an example. Let's look at
$$ f(I_5) = \{ [5n]_{\text{mod } 12} : n \in \mathbb Z \} $$

Notice that $[1]_{\text{mod }12} \in f(I_5)$, since $[1]_{\text{mod }12} = [5 \times 5]_{\text{mod }12}$. So $f(I_5)$ is the whole of $\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z $. Therefore, $f(I_5)$ is not prime (since an ideal must be a proper ideal in order to qualify as prime).

---

Let's do one more - perhaps a different example from the ones in the exercises. Let's look at

$$ f(I_2) = \{ [2n]_{\text{mod } 12} : n \in \mathbb Z \}. $$

To determine whether this is a prime ideal, we must determine whether
$ [xy]_{\text{mod 12}} \in f(I_2)$ implies $ [x]_{\text{mod 12}} \in f(I_2)$ or $ [y]_{\text{mod 12}} \in f(I_2)$. The answer is yes - $ [xy]_{\text{mod 12}} \in f(I_2)$  implies that $xy$ is even, which implies that either $x$ or $y$ is even, which implies that $ [x]_{\text{mod 12}} \in f(I_2)$ or $ [y]_{\text{mod 12}} \in f(I_2)$. So $f(I_2)$ is a prime ideal.

Alternatively, notice that $(\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z) / f(I_2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$, which is an *integral domain*. This is another way to see that $f(I_2)$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Many thanks. I expected that $f(I_5)$ will be a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ by the correspondence theorem as was stated by @Mark above. In other words, if $I_5$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z},$ then one following that comment, $f(I_5)$ would be prime in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, which it is not. What is wrong here ?

Comment: The correspondence theorem does _not_ say that $I \subset \mathbb Z$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$ iff $f(I)$ is prime in $\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$. The correspondence theorem says that $J \subset \mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$ is prime in $\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$ iff $f^{-1}(J)$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$. Note that if $J = f(I_5)$, then $f^{-1}(J)$ is $\mathbb Z$, not $I_5$.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry I have to bother you again. The structure of the elements of $f(I_k)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ seems to be not trivial. Let's take the example of $I_9 = \{...,-18,-9,0,9,18,27,...\}.$ Then, $f(I_9)=\{[9n]_{\text{mod} 12}: n\in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{..,[-9]_{\text{mod} 12}, [0]_{\text{mod} 12}, [9]_{\text{mod} 12},[18]_{\text{mod} 12},...\}.$ We may pick one such equivalence class, $[9]_{\text{mod} 12} = \{ a\in \mathbb{Z}: a = 9 \text{mod}12 \land a = 9k, k\in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{..,9,45,...\}.$ It's elements are spread out among equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: In particular, the image $f(I_9)$ seems to have more equivalence classes than the target space $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z} = \{[0],[1],...,[11]\}.$ I am quite a bit confused with the underlying structure of $f(I_k).$ Can you provide a comment on that ?

Comment: Well, $f(0) = [0], f(9) = [9], f(18) = [6], f(27) = [3], f(36) = [0], f(45) = [9], ...$

Comment: $f(I_9)$ is the principal ideal generated by $[3]$

Comment: I made it more complicated than it actually is. Thanks for the insight. You showed that $f(I_2)$ is prime in the target space by using the definition of a prime ideal. In case we would like to show $ J = f(I_9)$ is prime in the target space by rather using the correspondence theorem, one needs to show that $f^{-1}(J)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}.$ Is there a way to get the inverse image of an ideal ? In this case we even know it's generator. Maybe this helps, but I do not know how to do that. Actually by guessing one may find that $I=(3)\subset f^{-1}(J).$ It works in this simple case.

Comment: Actually, there is an easy way. Suppose $m$ and $n$ are integers and $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$. Let $I_m =(m) \subset \mathbb Z$, and let $f_n : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z /n\mathbb Z$. Then $J := f(I_m) = ([d]_{\text{mod } n})$, and $f^{-1}(J) = (d)$. These ideals are prime if and only if $d$ is a prime integer.

Comment: If you want prove my claim, then use the following elementary fact from arithmetic: Let $m, n$ and let $d$ be their greatest common divisor. If $k$ is some integer, then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $mx + my = k$ if and only if $k$ is divisible by $d$.

Comment: An element $[k]_{\text{mod } n}\in \mathbb Z/\mathbb Z_n$ is inside $f(I_m)$ iff it is equal to $f(mx)$ for some integer $x$, i.e. iff it is equal to $[mx]_{\text{mod } n}$ for some integer $x$. The equation $[k]_{\text{mod } n} = [mx]_{\text{mod }n}$ is satisfied iff there exists an integer $y$ such that $k = mx + ny$. Applying my elementary fact from arithmetic, we see that $[k]_{\text{mod }n}$ is in $f(I_m)$ iff $k$ is divisible by $d$. Therefore, $f(I_m)$ is the principal ideal generated by $[d]_{\text{mod }n}$.

Comment: Oops, there's a typo, it should say $mx + ny = k$ two comments up. And the $f$'s should be $f_n$'s. Sorry - it's hard typing maths on a phone.

Comment: So to summarise: the image of $I_{525}$ in $\mathbb Z/539\mathbb Z$ is the principal ideal generated by $[7]$. I know this because the gcd of $525$ and $539$ is $7$. This ideal is prime because the integer $7$ is prime.

Comment: ...and that $f^{-1}(f(I_{525}) = (7)$ in $\mathbb{Z},$ right ? In case $f(I_k)$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ such as $f(I_5),$ how one would find the inverse image?

Comment: Correct. Also, the way you find the inverse image works regardless of whether the ideal is prime. In the case of $f(I_5) \subset \mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$, we have $gcd(5, 12) = 1$, so $J=f(I_5) = ([1]_{\text{mod }(12})$ and $f^{-1}(J) = (1)$.

Comment: Many thanks indeed.